# Create any number of objects from byte array. Dhcp package C#

Tags: c#, parsing, byte, dhcp, payload

I'm currently working on a public library that will allow you to create a dhcp package with all kinds of options like dhcp options. When you create it, a byte array is created, which you can send as payload via a UdpSocket. I have created two classes for this: 1. dhcppacket, 2. dhcpoption. So far the creation of a Dhcp Packet with any DhcpOptions works already.

Now I want to parse incoming DhcpPackets, which are passed in form of a byte array, back to a DhcpPacket object to be able to read important information like the message type or from the passed DhcpOptions like subnet mask. The fixed part (beginning) of the DhcpPacket I have already agreed. But now I fail with the DhcpOptions, because they are variable. How to create X objects from a byte array.

Given is a byte-array with not given length

```
dhcpOptions = pPayload.Skip(240).ToArray();
```

From this payload I now want to create objects of the class "DhcpOption". Each Dhcp Option starts with a unique byte e.g. 0x01 = DhcpOption containing the subnet mask. Then follows a byte, which indicates the length of the DhcpOption including the following values. If, for example, a DNS server is communicated via a Dhcp option, the length is 0x04, since an IPv4 address is transferred as value. The total length of the Dhcp option in the payload is therefore 6 bytes. But since all options do not have the same length, I do not know how exactly I get to the start of the next DHCP option.

Example for creating a dhcp option from the ByteArray:

```
DhcpOption option = new DhcpOption{
    optionId = byteArray[0],
    optionLength = byteArray[1],
    optionValue = byteArray.Skip(2).Take(optionLength).ToArray(),
};
```

Searched are X-Objects of the class:

```
public class DhcpOption
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Define the DHCP options to be created by name
        /// </summary>
        public dhcpOptionIds optionId { get; set; } = new dhcpOptionIds();
        private byte[] optionIdBytes = new byte[] { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Define the required length for the optionValue
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] optionLength { get; set; } = new byte[] { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Define the value for the option e.g. subnet mask
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] optionValue { get; set; } = new byte[] { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the DHCP option as byte array. Is then specified as an option in the DhcpPacket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public byte[] buildDhcpOption()
        {
            object selected = Convert.ChangeType(optionId, optionId.GetTypeCode());
            optionIdBytes = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(selected, null) };

            return optionIdBytes.Concat(optionLength).Concat(optionValue).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Instead of a pure byte array I would like a list of dhcp options. So `List<DhcpOption>` can be used to search for a desired Dhcp-option with for or foreach and then read out the value.

Here is the GitHub repo, so I don't have to copy the code.

https://github.com/Marschall-dev/DhcpDotNet/blob/main/DhcpDotNet/DhcpDotNet/DhcpPacket.cs

Comment: C# managed code doesn't allow access to all the bits.  Either write a cpp project or use the dhcpsapi.dll.  See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dhcpsapi.DhcpGetClientInfo

Comment: Im using PacketDotNet to get the full Dhcp Payload

Comment: I looked at the dll and not sure if it actually works.  I do not thing you can directly from c# get the bytes in the packet.  Are you getting bytes with non zero values with the code?

Comment: @jdweng yes it returns the full payload from the udp layer. So if there is an Udp payload it return is with zero values. By using Pcap.Net you can go like this:
Datagram datagram = udpDatagram.Payload;

Source: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Interpreting-the-packets)

Comment: The new link is showing a c++ library, original didn't include that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed protocol you need to follow, the typical approach I use is a  [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=net-5.0)/BinaryWriter.

Create a memory stream from the byte-array and feed to the binaryReader. If you have a list of multiple different options, the data for each option should be prefixed by the type of option, and optionally, length. So you can first read the type of option, and then have a switch that handles each specific option type. Repeat this until all options are read.

Serializing and deserializing should usually be the inverse of each other, so you might want to use BinaryWriter for serialization. Unit tests are very useful to ensure you can serialize and deserialize messages without involving any network connectivity. If you do not need to follow a existing protocol I would recommend a serialization library, like protobuf.net.